# How to filter array to only return items that have at least one nested property contained in a whitelist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

What i'm essentially trying to do is filter my GitHub issues (via the REST API) to only show issues that contain labels matching my specific whitelist.

```js
const issues = [
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar" }, { name: "Baz" }],
    },
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Red" }, { name: "Green" }, { name: "Blue" }],
    },
];

const whitelist = ['Baz'];

// How to filter issues to only an issue that has at least one label contained in the whitelist?

const filtered = issues.filter(issue => issue.labels.forEach(label => whitelist.indexOf(label) > - 1);

// ?? not sure of something like this would work?
```

I'm getting stuck because a) the label names are nested and b) there are multiples, so I can't figure out how to iterate over the possible label names to return a filtered list of issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to do this using JS find:

```
const filtered = issues.filter(i=> i.labels.find(l => whitelist.find(w => w == l.name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

May it works.

```js
const issues = [
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar" }, { name: "Baz" }],
    },
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Red" }, { name: "Green" }, { name: "Blue" }],
    },
];

const whitelist = ['Baz'];

let filteredIssues = [];

issues.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.labels.length > 0) {
    i.labels.forEach(function(l) {
      if (whitelist.includes(l.name)) {
        filteredIssues.push(i);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(filteredIssues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if any labels are in your whitelist, it's only a small change to the code:

```js
const issues = [
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar" }, { name: "Baz" }],
    },
    {
        issue_name: "My issue",
        labels: [{ name: "Red" }, { name: "Green" }, { name: "Blue" }],
    },
];

const whitelist = ['Baz'];

const filtered = issues.filter(issue => issue.labels.some(label => whitelist.indexOf(label.name) > - 1));

// Filtered issues
console.log("Filtered issues:",filtered)
```